# Plotting the curve of a function with parametric integral using R

Tags: r

With

```
n<-3; rho<-0.5;
```

I want to draw the picture of the function

```
g<-function(r)
   {
     integrate(
       function(beta)
       {
         1/(cosh(beta)-rho*r)^(n-1)
       }
     ,lower=0,upper=Inf)
   }
```

I tried

```
curve(g(x),from=0,to=1)
```

but R complained that

> In cosh(beta) - rho * r : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I think all variables are scalar. So how to draw it correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
g<-function(r)
    {
      integrate(
        function(beta)
        {
          1/(cosh(beta)-rho*r)^(n-1)
        }
      ,lower=0,upper=Inf)$value   # integrate would return a list otherwise
    }
 gv <- Vectorize(g)  
 # Since `g` is not naturally going to handle the vector that `curve` will send
 curve(gv(x),from=0,to=1)
```

Comment: +1 Wow. Are you spying on me? That's literally the answer I was just about to post, complete with the choice of `gv <- Vectorize()`, and the addition of `$value`, almost letter for letter.

Comment: Yes, my mind reading powers now extend to potential answerers as well as those from posters.

Comment: Oops, I thought the message "1.568874 with absolute error < 1e-06" is friendly representation of 1.568874

Comment: I would like to add:  This shows why we (especially me :-) ) should *always* double-check the "Value" part of function documentation, to avoid just this sort of confusion as to what the function returns.  The naive user (aka me most of the time) types `integrate(funcfoo,0,1)` and gets a nice number printed to the console, and completely forgets that `integrate(funcfoo,0,1) ->intfoo` produces something rather different.

Comment: Yeah, it would be good if I could claim to have always checked the "Value" section but in this case I just used str() on g(0) and was immediately reminded of the more complex nature of the returned object.